# i keep getting "Invalid result type, int expected, <class 'NoneType'> found"

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    count=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if j!=i:
                if A[i]==A[j]:
                    count = count+1
                else:
                    count = count+0

        if count==0:
            return A[i]
pass
```

Comment: Can you give an example of A?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the purpose of this code is to loop through list A and return the first value if it does not have a duplicate.

```
else:
    count = count+0
```

This is redundant, and you can merge the two if statements above it.

```py
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    count=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if j != i and A[i] == A[j]:
                count += 1

        if count==0:
            return A[i]
```

The issue is that if `count` *never* equals 0, you don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found an answer yet? I was just working on the same question on Codility. It has to do with the fact that you're only checking for a value of one. The description was very vague, but it basically comes down to also checking for odd values.

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    count=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if j != i and A[i] == A[j]:
                count += 1

        if count % 2 == 1:
            return A[i]
    return -1
```

https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What happens if both loops finish executing and count is not an odd number?   The final result will return a None, which is the same reason why the OP is getting the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks @ewong! You're absolutely correct. For this problem one of the assumptions he is allowed to make is that "all but one of the values in A occur an even number of times". So there should always be an odd value.. but I'll edit my answer to have a default return as well